# Geogebra applets in posts?

Tags: feature-request

Is there any provision of adding Geogebra applets in answers? I think it would be really useful in many answers, especially in geometry. Is there any way, if not, why do not we add it? It would be extremely useful where dynamic content in helpful, many demonstrations could be made, could be used in graphing, proving, disproving conjectures among other things?

Comment: If you can figure out how to upload it on an external server and then link to it in your answer, I'm sure you could do that.  To add this would have to be done at a high level in SE, and likely necessarily in a way that it would be accessible in every SE site, so I would say the chances of this request being fulfilled are nonexistent.

Comment: Uploading to [GeoGebraTube](http://www.geogebratube.org/) looks like an option. I can indeed see and use the uploads there. It looks like you need to register to upload. You could then link to your upload.

Comment: @J.W.Perry Can I convince you to make that an answer? (Just so it is more prominently displayed.)

Comment: @WillieWong  that would officiate my first post in meta other than my community ad. Thanks for the encouragement, it takes me time to warm up to a crowd. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upload your applet to [GeoGebraTube](http://www.geogebratube.org/). You need to register to upload, but it is free, and then you can link to your "student worksheet". The interactivity works quite well. An entertaining example (to me) is [Test Yourself: Reflection](http://www.geogebratube.org/student/m57686).